# DryadOpt (A library for parallel branch and Bound ) - availablity

Tags: apache, hadoop, breadth-first-search, hama

I am trying to implement a parallel branch and bound BFS. I am interested in using DryadOpt  which runs on top of Dryad LinQ. Has anyone obtained DryadOpt. I know we can get academic version of DryadLinQ and it is also present on Azure but is there any way I can get DryadOpt. Can apache hama handle  a parallel branch and bound BFS

Answer (score 1):

Although this is possible with Hama, implementing this with BSP is not efficient (you can branch, but bounding requires global synchronization). Hama will have constructs in the future to enable this.

But for know, I would recommend you to use `BranchReduce` on YARN by cloudera.

https://github.com/cloudera/branchreduce

(not tested if it works, maybe just write a mail to them)